# Dynamic CSS style class that has a space or comma

Tags: css, stylesheet

I am setting a style class dynamically based on the status value such as:

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.status}" styleClass="#{item.status}"/>
```

And a few rendered examples:

```
<span class="Incomplete">Incomplete</span>
<span class="Expired">Expired</span>
<span class="Expiring Soon">Expiring Soon</span>
<span class="Incomplete, Overdue">Incomplete, Overdue</span>
```

The value is in a database that I don't control. How do I do the CSS styles to target these? Even though the last two have a space and a comma, they are all really single classes.

This is what I have that works, but is it working by a fluke or is the right way?

For either `Expired` or `Incomplete` I want red:

```
.Expired, .Incomplete {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

For an `Expiring Soon` I want yellow

```
.Expiring, .Soon {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

An `Incomplete, Overdue`:

```
.Incomplete, .Overdue {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the comma to assign multiple classes to an `html` container. The last span should be `<span class="Incomplete Overdue">` to assign both.

Comment: `.Expiring {}`, `.Soon {}` and `.Expiring.Soon {}` will all target that element.  `.Overdue {}` will certainly target the last one, but I don't know how the browser will handle the comma in the html.  Browsers may actually behave different.  To be safe I would steer clear of `Incomplete {}`, especially if `.Overdue {}` does the job.

Comment: @d_z90 the statuses come in from a db I can not or we prefer to not change.  So the comma stays.

Comment: Then you either modify the name of the class after you fetch it from the database, or you follow @Marvin's answer. Cheers man!

Comment: @d_z90 that is actually a good idea, I could still display the common in the application, but filter out the comma or the space when inserting it into the styleClass field in my facelet/JSF tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is what I have that works but is it working by a fluke or is the right way?

Your examples only work because in these specific examples CSS handles your *single class* as two separate classes. Especially this one:

```
<span class="Incomplete, Overdue">Incomplete, Overdue</span>

.Incomplete, .Overdue {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

only works because of the `.Overdue`. To use commas and spaces in class names you would have to do it like this:

```css
[class="Incomplete, Overdue"] {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="Incomplete Overdue">Incomplete Overdue</span>
<span class="Incomplete, Overdue">Incomplete, Overdue</span>
```

The above is called [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

---

It is also possible to escape some characters like the comma in CSS (`.Incomplete\, { ... }`). For the whitespace thing you could simple combine this with the concept of grouping CSS selectors. In fact there are two selectors in the HTML `.Inclomplete,` and `.Overdue` but with the following CSS we can say that only the combination of both (*with a whitespace in between*) should be selected (which then would behave like a *single class*):

```css
.Incomplete\,.Overdue {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="Incomplete Overdue">Incomplete Overdue</span>
<span class="Incomplete, Overdue">Incomplete, Overdue</span>
<span class="Overdue">Overdue</span>
```

Comment: Exactly, since when I put a .Overdue after the others in my style sheet it overrode the other.  The [] around the class is what I think I am looking for.

Comment: So [class="Incomplete, Overdue"] works but if we come up with a new status of just "Overdue" and I accidently style that last, it will still override the [class="Incomplete, Overdue"].  I'll just need to be careful.  I've learned a lot from all, especially you and dognose but will accept your answer as you have the lower reputation.

Answer (score 1):

> For either Expired or Incomplete I want Red
>
> ```
> .Expired, .Incomplete {
>     color: white;
>     background-color: red;
> }
> ```

That's correct: `OR`

> An Expiring Soon I want Yellow
>
> ```
> .Expiring, .Soon {
>    color: black;
>    background-color: yellow; }
> ```

Here you should use `AND`, meaning no comma, no whitespace:

```
.Expiring.Soon {
   color: black;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

(Else, every entry that is EITHER `.Expiring` OR `.Soon` will be yellow.)

The invalid `comma` in the HTML (CSS classes are separated with whitespaces) - I'm not sure about if it has an impact. It might depend on the browser, whether it parses this as two classes (`Incomplete` and `Overdue`) or even as two classes with one containing a comma: (`Incomplete,` and `Overdue`)

---

I did some quick tests about the `Comma`. It seems like the browser (Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Firefox) are ignoring classes that contain a `,` inside the HTML markup.

That means, your last example

```
<span class="Incomplete, Overdue">Incomplete, Overdue</span>
```

is just rendered as

```
<span class="Overdue">Incomplete, Overdue</span>
```

```css
.test1 {
  background-color:red;
}

.test2 {
  border:2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1, test2">
  with comma after test1
</div>

<div class="test1 test2,">
  with comma after test2
</div>

<div class="test1,test2">
  with comma no whitespace
</div>

<div class="test1 , test2">
  with comma double whitespace
</div>
```

Comment: Great, I guess I was aware of the OR by using comma separated, but didn't really know that concatenating both together turned it into an AND

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the HTML you could target like so...

```css
.Expired,
.Incomplete {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.Expiring.Soon {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Overdue {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="Incomplete">Incomplete</span>
<span class="Expired">Expired</span>
<span class="Expiring Soon">Expiring Soon</span>
<span class="Incomplete, Overdue">Incomplete, Overdue</span>
```